# SlideTransition in Kivy - slide direction fails

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am having issues with the slide direction using SlideTransition in Kivy. When implementing a button-specific slide direction, the direction seems to work fine only occasionally. However, it fails in other circumstances.

To reproduce the problem, please feel free to use the following code:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App # Use of fields and methods of Kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class Screen3(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("style.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

myApp = MyApp()
myApp.run()
```

style.kv:

```
#: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition()
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 1"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.0}
        Button:
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "screen2"
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"bottom": 0.8, "left": 1}
            text: "Screen 2 (slide left)"
            font_size: 30

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 2"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.0}

        Button:
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "screen1"
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "right": 1}
            text: "Screen 1 (slide right)"
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "screen3"
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "left": 1}
            text: "Screen 3 (slide left)"
            font_size: 30

<Screen3>:
    name: "screen3"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 3"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.0}
        Button:
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "screen1"
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "left": 1}
            text: "Screen 1 (slide right)"
            font_size: 30
```

I am experiencing the following problem: Upon clicking on "Slide 2" in the first slide and "Slide 3" in the second slide, both disappearing to the left as specified, clicking "Slide 1" in the third slide results in slide direction "left", although the specified direction is "right". Something seems to override the slide direction?

Did anyone experience similar problems and does know how to solve them? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The screen was displayed before the given direction. Therefore, it used the previous Slide Transition direction i.e. left. You have the same problem in a couple of places.

```
Button:
    on_release: 
        app.root.current = "screen1"
        app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
```

## Solution

Set the Slide Transition direction first, and then set current to the desire screen name. Please refer to the example for details.

```
Button:
    on_release:
        app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
        app.root.current = "screen1"
```

## Example

### style.kv

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition()
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:

<Screen1>:
    name: "screen1"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 1"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.0}
        Button:
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
                app.root.current = "screen2"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"bottom": 0.8, "left": 1}
            text: "Screen 2 (slide left)"
            font_size: 30

<Screen2>:
    name: "screen2"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 2"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.0}

        Button:
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
                app.root.current = "screen1"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "right": 1}
            text: "Screen 1 (slide right)"
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
                app.root.current = "screen3"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "left": 1}
            text: "Screen 3 (slide left)"
            font_size: 30

<Screen3>:
    name: "screen3"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen 3"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1.0}
        Button:
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
                app.root.current = "screen1"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.8/3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "left": 1}
            text: "Screen 1 (slide right)"
            font_size: 30
```

Comment: I see! Thank you for your answer, my bad!